# Oracle apex dynamic date time picker plugin minimum and maximum date

Tags: date, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, oracle-apex-5.1

I have added a dynamic date time picker plugin to my oracle apex application. I want to set maximum date to this date picker. current date(or sysdate ) is the maximum date I want to set, the dates after current date should not be available for selection in the date picker.In the default apex date picker I add

```
 +0d
```

in the maximum date field to set maximum date to current date. But this does not works with dynamic date time picker plugin.Plugin link : [Apex dynamic date picker plugin link](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:1921260227697::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.PLANETAPEX.DYNAMICDATETIMEPICKER). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing and managed to do it today. Here's my solution.

1. Create a dynamic action in the first Datepicker Calendar with the **Change** event.
2. Create the **true action** "Execute Javascript Code" and use the following code:
   `$('#P1_SECOND_CALENDAR').datepicker("option","minDate",$("#P1_FIRST_CALENDAR").val());`

This function should make the second calendar set its minimum date to the one you've chosen on the first one, and it should happen when you pick it. Previous days should be greyed out on the second calendar once you open it to pick the second date.

Just replace the variables I used for calendars for the ones you have and it should work.

Checking the variables here again, I didn't choose a minimum date on the second Datepicker and APEX automatically chose a "+0d" value for it. It shouldn't be a problem. Try following these steps and see if it works.